# Were these lines from Star Wars inspired by David Bowie's "Space Oddity"?

Tags: star-wars

David Bowie's "Space Oddity" contains the following lines:

> Ground control to Major Tom
>
> Your circuit's dead, there's something wrong
>
> Can you hear me, major tom?

This is somewhat similar to the famous "Luke, you've turned off your targeting computer! What's wrong?" from *Star Wars: A New Hope*. (Though of course Luke keeps his radio-circuit on, unlike Major Tom.)

More striking are the following lines:

> Tell my wife I love her very much.
>
> She knows.

This is very similar to Harrison Ford's famous <s>ad-libbed</s> "I know" in response to Leia telling Han that she loves him.

Were either or both of these lines in *Star Wars* inspired by "Space Oddity"?

Answer (score 9):

According to J.W. Rinzler's excellent "[The Making of Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Making_of_The_Empire_Strikes_Back)" (reproduced [here on Yahoo Movies](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/the-empire-strikes-back-i-love-you-i-know-119550611107.html)) the line was largely the result of a back-and-forth conversation between Harrison Ford and the film's screenwriter Irvin Kershner. At first the line was written as “***Just remember that, ‘cause I’ll be back.”***, followed by "***Don’t worry about this***", followed by just "***I'll be back***", finally followed by the iconic "***I know***".

It's hard to say whether Ford was inspired by Bowie but it's quite easy to see how the line evolved over time rather than being inspired by a single leap of Ford's imagination:

> “I think she ought to just say, ‘I love you,’ as I’m passing by her,”
>   Ford suggests to Kershner. Later in the conversation, he makes the
>   change to his own line, saying, “If she says, ‘I love you,’ and I say,
>   ‘I know,’ it’s beautiful and it’s acceptable and it’s funny.”
>
> So it’s true that the iconic line was penned by Ford, but it wasn’t
>   improvised on the spot: It was hashed out with Kershner before the
>   shoot. Ford also wanted to add a line of reassurance to Leia
>   —something like “Don’t worry about this” — which eventually became his
>   saying to Chewbacca, “You have to take care of her.” Han Solo’s final
>   scripted line, “I’ll be back,” ended up on the cutting room floor,
>   because Kershner wanted to make it clear that Han Solo might not
>   survive the carbon freeze. “You can’t [reassure her] because you don’t
>   know whether this is the end or not,” the director said to Ford.
>
> Ironically, that tender moment resulted in a fight between Ford and
>   Carrie Fisher, who was annoyed that her co-star made changes to their
>   scene without her input. When it came time for Han and Leia to profess
>   their love, the two actors still weren’t speaking. “Harrison is a very
>   fine actor. I regarded that scene as entirely his, which is why I gave
>   him so much opportunity to tell me how he thought we should treat it,”
>   Kerschner explains in Rinzler’s book. “That led to a little tension
>   with Carrie.”
>
> When Kershner put his first cut of The Empire Strikes Back together,
>   executive producer George Lucas pushed back against the new dialogue,
>   fearing that the audience would laugh at Han’s line. In a 2010 Vanity
>   Fair interview, Kershner said that Lucas insisted on doing two preview
>   screenings, one with Han Solo’s scripted line (which Kershner had also
>   shot) and another with Ford’s version. “At the first preview in San
>   Francisco, the house broke up after Han Solo said ‘I know,’” Kershner
>   recalls. “When the film was over, people came up and said that is the
>   most wonderful line and it worked. So George decided not to have the
>   second screening.”